# custom post type redirects to home page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

**I created this custom post type**

```
 function my_custom_post_game() {
 $labels = array(
'name'               => _x( 'Game', 'post type general name' ),
'singular_name'      => _x( 'Games', 'post type singular name' ),
'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Game' ),
'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Game' ),
'rewrite'            =>array( 'slug' => 'game' ),
'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Game' ),
'new_item'           => __( 'New Game' ),
'all_items'          => __( 'All Games' ),
'view_item'          => __( 'View Game' ),
'search_items'       => __( 'Search Game' ),
'not_found'          => __( 'No Games found' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Games found in the Trash' ), 
'parent_item_colon'  => '',
'menu_name'          => 'Games'
);
$args = array(
'labels'        => $labels,
'description'   => 'Holds our Games and Game specific data',
'public'        => true,
'menu_position' => 5,
'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','custom-fields',             'comments' ),
 'has_archive'   => true,
);
register_post_type( 'games', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_game' );
```

**This is the loop on homepage**

```
 $counter = 0;
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Game', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
     echo $post_id[rand(0,sizeof($post_id))];
     if($counter < 2){
       ?>
       <a href=<?php get_post_permalink()?>>
        <div id="mypost" class="col-md-5" style="min-height:400px;">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large');
         ?>
        </div>
        </a>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <?php
    $counter++;
     } 
    else {?>
    <a href=<?php get_post_permalink()?>>
     <div id="mypost" class="col-md-3" href=<?php get_permalink()?>>
         <!-- post display -->  <?php echo get_post_permalink()?>
         <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
        </div>
    </a>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
       <?php 
       }
     endwhile; ?>
```

permalink gives 
    http://localhost/indigamer/?post_type=game&p=63

but when I right-click on the div block and copy link location, it gives a link to homepage

I have created single-game.php in my theme's root folder

here is the code

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <main id="main" class="site-main  site-main--single" role="main">

    test

    </main><!-- #main -->

</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: still not working. same problem

Comment: Did you get every post in your homepage?
Could you please let me know did you used page template for home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few problems in your code.

try adding:

```
$args = array(
'labels'        => $labels,
'description'   => 'Holds our Games and Game specific data',
'public'        => true,
'menu_position' => 5,
'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','custom-fields',             'comments' ),
 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'games'),
 'has_archive'   => true,
);
register_post_type( 'games', $args );
```

in the  WP query, use the slug:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'game', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
```

don't forget to add

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

EDIT: Saw some more errors:
You need to be doing

```
href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>"
```

Comment: Are you able to visit the actual post?

Comment: href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>"  
this solved the problem thank you !!!!

Comment: what? No I mean what is the final html output that you are getting

Comment: html output for
 <a href=<?php echo get_post_permalink()?>>
is
<a href="http://localhost/indigamer/?post_type=game&amp;p=64">